# Writing JSP Tags with 0+ key/value parameters

Tags: jsp, jstl, jsp-tags

I'm currently working on a project that I'm required to use JSP for, and I'm trying to write a custom tag to generate A links (Because there are some parameters that are always provided on all of the links regardless, so I want to encapsulate all of this in one place).

Ideally I want to be able to write my links like:

```
<h:link value="${policy.name}" href="show">
    <h:param name="id" value="${policy.id}" />
    .... There will be an arbitrary number of these, with arbitrary names and values ....
</h:link>
```

And have this write a link:

```
<a href="show?id=1&customer=234" />
```

Where "customer" is one of the parameters that is always present.

So far I've tried to do this by using jsp:doBody inside my tag, and having the body of the tag be either c:param or spring:param tags, but neither of those work. From looking around, the best I can come up with is either to write my custom tags in Java - which I'm really loathe to do as it then starts to mean that my view is written in a split of JSP and Java - or else to do something very hacky like building a Map and passing that in to the tag instead.

Is there a better way of achieving something like this?

Answer (score 1):

So, it turns out that what you can do is use Dynamic Attributes by specifying at the top of your tag:

```
<%@ tag dynamic-attributes="dynattrs" %>
```

This will then make available inside your tag an attribute called *dynattrs* that contains all of the attributes that weren't otherwise used. This is a Map and can be used as such. Thus, I can then call my tag like:

```
<h:link value="${policy.name}" href="show" id="${policy.id} />
```

and the *id* attribute will be available as a single entry in the *dynattrs* Map.

Answer (score -1):

Writing tags is very easy: place them under **WEB-INF/tags**

```
<!-- myTag.tag -->
<%@ tag language="java" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>

<%@ attribute name="id" description="Customer" required="true"%>
<%@ attribute name="customer" description="Id" required="true"%>

<a href="show?id=${id}&customer=${customer}" />
```

HTML

```
<%@ taglib prefix="tags" tagdir="/WEB-INF/tags"%>

<tags:myTag id="1" customer="James Bond" />
```

Map Tag

```
<!-- myMapTag.tag -->
<%@ tag language="java" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>

<%@ attribute name="map" description="My Key Value Map" type="java.util.Map" required="true"%>

<c:forEach items="${map}" var="pair">
     <a href="show?id=${pair.key}&customer=${pair.value}" />
</c:forEach>
```

Servlet/Portlet

```
Map<Long, String> pairMap = new HashMap<Long, String>();
pairMap.put(1L, "YooZoo");
pairMap.put(2L, "YooZoo Oh Oh");

request.setAttribute("pairMap", true);
```

HTML

```
<%@ taglib prefix="tags" tagdir="/WEB-INF/tags"%>

<tags:myMapTag map="${pairMap}" />
```

Comment: This doesn't actually answer my question though. Writing tags is easy. Writing tags that take an arbitrary number of key/value pairs as parameters that can then be used inside the tag is something that I can't find any decent way of doing...

Comment: So in your example, how would I actually call the tag without the awful hacky solution of jsp:useBean and c:set?

Comment: Something like that, I'm typing out of my head so it may not be 100% accurate but you get the idea. Updated answer.

Comment: That's in the Java controller though. I'm wanting to do everything in the JSP. 

Per my example, I've got a JSP that is rendering an HTML page, and is writing hyperlinks from a summary table to each individual element in the table. I want to write a JSP tag file that encapsulates writing a link so that I don't have to repeat all of the common parameters between every single link in the entire system many times, so that the JSP template can use this passing in the values and it will generate the appropriate <a href=""></a> markup.

Comment: I guess you can do the same from a scriptlet. But it's a bad practice. Don't mix Java code into JSP - only EL and JSTL.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/27864/discussion-between-graham-and-kayz1)